# Fury of Dracula 3rd ed. - Defeated Hunter and Skipping Actions

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In Fury of Dracula 3rd edition, when hunter is defeated, he/she is temporarily removed from the board, and placed at the nearest hospital at the **next dawn** (as per Rules Reference). This means that if it was a combat at dusk, the hunter skips their night action, and if it was a combat at dawn, the hunter skips both their day and night action, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. When you are defeated you determine the closest hospital (the one that is the fewest roads away) and then the figure is removed from the board and placed at the hospital at the next dawn.

If the combat was at dusk, the hunter only skips the night action. If the hunter If the hunter is defeated at dawn they would end up losing both their next night and day action.